# Use User defined Table Type as a parameter to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have used an user-defined table type as a parameter in a stored procedure.
But for table type with only few columns.

For that I have to generate `DataTable` as follows::

```
        System.Data.DataTable processedTable = new System.Data.DataTable();

        processedTable.Columns.Add("DosID", typeof(long));
        processedTable.Columns.Add("PayLC", typeof(decimal));
        processedTable.Columns.Add("PayIC", typeof(decimal));
```

In code above, it was ok to form a `DataTable` with only 3 columns.

But I have a stored procedure which requires a table with 30 columns.

Is there any better way for creating that `DataTable` in my C# code?

Comment: Is it not OK to set your table like you do with 3-column-table?

Comment: I have one table-value type parameter SP with 30 columns. Thats why

Comment: You need to write this code to name your columns which should match with Table Type. The only way i could see is to use reflection to iterate through the properties and add columns to datatable with each column name same as property's. But, in this approach, you need to ensure that your property names and datatype column names are same.

Comment: @Rahul : I think make definition of 30-column-table-type is a small effort when you only do it once :)

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan ; Thanks :D , that is 1 of the option i am having. But I am just thinking of how I can Optimize this Lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need above code to name your columns which should match with Table Type. The only other way i could see is to use `reflection` to iterate through the properties and add columns to datatable with each column name same as property's. But, in this approach, you need to ensure that your property names and datatype column names are same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this matches your exact requirement or not 
but you can modify the code and use this for your dynamic generation of TABLE

```
public void CreateUserDefinedTable(string tableName)
{
    string connectionString = "Give your Connection String";
    string sqlQuery = "select c.name as COLUMN_NAME, t.name as TYPE_NAME,c.max_length as MAX_LENGTH " +
                        "from sys.columns c, sys.types t " +
                        "where c.object_id = (select type_table_object_id from sys.table_types where name = '"+tableName+"') " +
                        "and t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id " +
                        "order by c.column_id ";
    string data = "", type = "";
    DataTable processedTable = new DataTable();
    DataColumn newcolumn = new DataColumn();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conObj);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["TYPE_NAME"].ToString())
            {
                case "varchar":
                    newcolumn = processedTable.Columns.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString(), typeof(string));
                    newcolumn.MaxLength = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MAX_LENGTH"].ToString());
                    break;
                case "nvarchar":
                    newcolumn = processedTable.Columns.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString(), typeof(string));
                    newcolumn.MaxLength = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["MAX_LENGTH"].ToString());
                    break;
                case "char":
                    newcolumn= processedTable.Columns.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString(), typeof(char));
                    break;
                case "int":
                    newcolumn = processedTable.Columns.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString(), typeof(int));
                    break;
                case "float":
                    newcolumn = processedTable.Columns.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString(), typeof(float));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Here table name refers to the type you have created in DB